# Transfer function for a quadcopter with linear velocity inputs

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I found the control for a quadcopter using the angular velocities or thrust power as the input, but I need a model where I can set the initial and final position (for example, from (0,0,1) to (0,1,1)). The inputs of the quadcopter are the linear velocities. I'm using a PID controller

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are searching for something like [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7321330). Those kind of papers can be found in  [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), e.g. searching *quadcopter lagrangian mechanic*.

From your knowledge of PID, I assume you are some sort of engineer. If you are a trained electrical engineer, I'd recommend you read some book on [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics)/[(Euler-)Langrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) Mechanic, with which you should be able to understand said papers.

I like [Kibble/Berkshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Mechanics_(Kibble_and_Berkshire_book))'s book. From that point on, you have non-linear ODEs and know what to do with them.
Does this help?